# How to allow my vpn client access to remote LAN(eth1)?

Tags: vpn, iptables, pptpd

My ubuntu server has two if: `eth0, eth1`.

```
eth0: Public IP  
eth1: 192.168.0.2
```

I've configure down `eth0` for a vpn server using pptpd.

The `vpn ip_range` is `192.168.100.234-248`

```
#/etc/pptpd.conf
logwtmp
bcrelay eth2
localip 192.168.100.1
remoteip 192.168.100.234-238,192.168.100.245
```

Now from my client can connect to vpn server and get `192.168.100.234` address.

But I can't access anything in 192.168.0.2/24 LAN network.

I've try to setup `iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT` and also a `-t nat` settings.

But seems no effects.

How to done this work correct?

Thanks a lot.

Here is my server and client related info https://gist.github.com/4635571

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Do you have IPv4 forwarding enabled for your kernel? Please post the output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/forwarding`. And what does the route table look like on the clients? (post the output of `route -n` on the client)

Comment: all results for `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/forwarding` is 1, I think forwarding options is enable.

Should I set route manually in vpn client?

Comment: No, you should push the route from the server (if possible, I've worked with OpenVPN). The client can't read the route from the sky, you know. :) Just post all relevant configuration files and the route tables.

Comment: I use the pptpd. I would try the OpenVPN to solve this problem. My configurations and network stats posted to https://gist.github.com/4635571  Is there anything missing there? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've found this OpenVPN guide. Is bridged VPN help? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN

Comment: As appears from the output you provided, your client does not have a route to `192.168.0.0/24` over the PPP connection. Moreover, it already has this network on a local `en1` interface! You can't have duplicate IP ranges here. So you'll need to change the IP range on at least one end to overcome this and then add a route to the PPP endpoint for the network. And please **edit** your question with all relevant information. This is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solutions and has been tested. It just works.

My ubuntu server has two network interfaces:
eth1 - wan
eth2 - lan 192.168.0.2

And the VPN service use 192.168.100.1 as its address.

VPN client will get an address from 192.168.100.234-238.

Following commands let VPN clients access to the other clients behind the server's LAN.
e.g. 192.168.0.100

Using iptables to setup nat.

```
# ubuntu vpn server 
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

And client add route manually.

```
# mac os x client
sudo route add 192.168.0.0/24 192.168.100.1
```