# Allow incoming For public ip while in openvpn connections?

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

i asked before how can i connect to my public ip when i connected to my ssh in openvpn and i find this solution

> Lets assume your server's:
>
> Public IP is `a.b.c.d` Public IP Subnet is `a.b.c.0/24` Default
>   Gateway is `x.x.x.1` `eth0` is device to gateway `iproute2` is your
>   friend here. Do the following:
>
> ```
> ip rule add table 128 from a.b.c.d
> ip route add table 128 to a.b.c.0/24 dev eth0
> ip route add table 128 default via x.x.x.1
> ```

but the problem now when i in connection opnvpn i can't connect to my other servers using my public ip

for example `x.x.x.x` my other server and open 1267 port:

(before connect to openvpn)

from browsing my public ip and get result connection from `x.x.x.x` the status is online

(after connect to openvpn)

from browsing my public ip and get result connection from `x.x.x.x` the status is offline

and i think this problem cause incoming non OPENVPN connections

Comment: check this out.. could [help](http://askubuntu.com/questions/245192/how-to-allow-my-vpn-client-access-to-remote-laneth1)